# How to identify a movie from a screen shot?

Tags: identify-this-movie, faq

Movie identification questions with only a screen shot are not considered high quality questions, but they are indeed questions.

I would like to know what steps can be taken to identify a movie from a screen shot on my own.

For example, I found this screen shot **(warning: graphic imagery)** while browsing some Facebook pages and I would like to know what movie it's from. How do I identify this movie on my own? Is it even possible?

> [image]

Comment: Is this not a question for META?

Comment: Too bad I didn't see (**warning: graphic imagery**) until after I shat myself.

Comment: @n_b I thought it was a bluff to start with; I will not sleep soundly tonight...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Probably the best start to identifying a movie from a screenshot, is opening **[Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/imghp)** and dragging the screenshot into the search box.

Comment: Much easier than loading an image to my phone. Was unaware that either solution existed, but this is much easier and it seems that it may be more accurate. Image search shows Carnival of souls while goggles says Jacobs Ladder. I find more references to CoS than JL.

Comment: It is indeed the '98 version of Carnival of Souls.

Answer (score 7):

Another good option is **[TinEye](http://tineye.com/)**, which is a reverse image search service, and it's quite useful for finding an image online in different sites.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way: If you are using Google Chrome you can right click on an image and select "Search Google for this image" and voila!

The picture you have posted is from Jacob's Ladder (1990 Film).

Comment: Thanks. It's actually from Carnival of Souls, I watched it 2 weeks ago (horrible movie btw).

Comment: @DustinDavis - A horror movie? You don't say :P I've just had to binge watch 2 series of My Little Pony to erase that scene from my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Download the *gophoto.it* extension for chrome, and whenever you right-click any image you get an extra option labelled "Search for similar images".